# how to disable Enter key action for a specific view in an android app?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I have a view in my app which contains a ListView. Sometimes a row in the list is highlighted when the activity starts or resumes and if I hit the Enter key (on the physical keyboard of my device) then it does a click on the row. 
I tried to override the OnKeyListener of the main view or of the list or to set it to null but it didn't change anything. 
How can I achieve this ?

EDIT : sorry if it wasn't clear.

I want the ListView to react on clicks but only if I touch the screen, not when I push the enter key. And I don't want the list to react to the physical arrow keys. Basically a row should be focused or clicked in any other way than touching the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% right but since my view only had a ListView the following code did what I wanted :

```
menuListView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set focus to another view from your screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear, but I suppose that you want your ListView to *not* react to clicks on rows. You're better off with returning false for [.areAllItemsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29) on your adapter, and false for every row for [.isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29). This way you can switch off unneeded interactions on rows in your list.

Comment: It's not what I meant, sorry for the misunderstanding. I edited my question.

Comment: You're not responding to my question but thanks anyway, this helped me to solve something else :)